# Laravel 5 Form Submit and Next Button

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to add next and previous button and it doesn't go to next page, but actually try to submit information instead. How can i enable submit button at the end of the questions ?

```
@if(! $questions->lastItem())
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
@else
    <a href="{{ $questions->previousPageUrl() }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Previous Question</button></a>
    <a href="{{ $questions->nextPageUrl() }}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Next Question</button></a>
@endif
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide more information regarding what exactly is happening with your code. Remember, we have no idea what you're trying to do, nor what is happening with your code.

---

That said, I feel that wrapping a button inside an anchor is not the way to go with it. If I were you, I would just add the `.btn .btn-primary` class to the anchor itself and see if that works.

---

Also the php logic is ringing a bell. `$questions->lastItem()` returns the number of the last item in the slice. Adding the NOT logic operator there will almost always return `false` (the `lastitem` will most likely be not equal to 0 and, thus, since 0 is false, anything else is considered to be true. NOT true is false). Thus you will never see the submit button. I think that what you're looking for is:

```
@if (! $questions-> hasMorePages())
{{-- Show the submit button --}}
@else
{{-- Bla Bla Bla --}}
@endif
```

**Also, if I understand what you're doing correctly, you will lose all information present in the questions form when going to a different page.**

Ps: Don't forget to remove the previous page link from the first page and to have it stay at the last (you're gonna want to have both the submit and the previous page available in the last page).